# Getting EmailField error in CharField while submitting form in Django 1.9

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms, django-custom-user

I am a beginner, developing my Django project. I am trying to make my own email based authentications model. I have done some work, and successful in creating superusers and users through django admin platform and logging them in through login form view, But I am not able to create users through   my user register form, I get errors like 'Enter a valid email address.' in the field of 'name' ( a CharField).
My code:

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from ca_portal import settings
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
            AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin)
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.core.mail import send_mail


class CampusAmbassadorManager(BaseUserManager):

    def _create_user(self, email,name,college,password, is_staff,
                            is_superuser, **extra_fields):
        now = timezone.now()
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Campus Ambassadors must have an email address')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email = email,
                        name = name,
                        college = college,
                        is_staff = is_staff,
                        is_superuser = is_superuser,
                        last_login = now,
                        date_joined = now,
                        **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using = self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, name, college, password=None, **extra_fields):
        user = self._create_user(email, name, college, password, False, False, **extra_fields)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, name, college, password, **extra_fields):
        user = self._create_user(email, name, college, password, True, True, **extra_fields)
        return user

class CampusAmbassador(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    """My own custom user class"""

    email       =   models.EmailField(_('email address'),max_length=255,
                                unique=True, db_index=True)
    name        =   models.CharField(_('name'),max_length = 100)
    college     =   models.CharField(_('college name'),max_length = 140)
    date_joined =   models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active   =   models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff    =   models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects     =   CampusAmbassadorManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Campus Ambassador')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Campus Ambassdors')
        # abstract = True

    def get_full_name(self):
        """Return the email."""
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        """Return the email."""
        return self.email

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None):
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email,[self.email])
        #sends an email to this user.
```

backends.py :

```
from django.conf import settings
#from django.contrib.auth.models import *
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password #important to note that is resides in hashers

from .models import CampusAmbassador

class EmailAuthBackend(object):

    def authenticate(self, email=None, password=None):
        """
        authentication method, check the email/password and return user.
        """
        try:
            user = CampusAmbassador.objects.get(email = email)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except CampusAmbassador.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            user = CampusAmbassador.objects.get(pk = user_id)
            if user.is_active:
                return user
            return None

        except CampusAmbassador.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

forms.py :

```
from django import forms
from .models import CampusAmbassador

#http://blackglasses.me/2013/09/17/custom-django-user-model/
# Form for registring a new CampusAmbassador

class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=
    {'class': 'form-control','type':'text','name': 'email'}), label="Email")

    name = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=
    {'class': 'form-control','type':'text','name': 'name'}), label="Name")

    college = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=
    {'class': 'form-control','type':'text','name': 'college'}), label="College")

    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=
    {'class':'form-control','type':'password', 'name': 'password1'}),label="Password")

    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=
    {'class':'form-control','type':'password', 'name': 'password2'}),label="Password (again)")

    class Meta:
        model = CampusAmbassador
        fields = ['email','name','password1','password2']

    field_order = ['name','college','email','password1','password2']

    # def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #     super(RegistrationForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    #     self.fields['email'].required = True
    #

    def clean(self):
        """
        Verifies that the values entered into the password fields match
        NOTE : errors here will appear in 'non_field_errors()'
        """
        cleaned_data = super(RegistrationForm, self).clean()

        if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data and 'password2' in self.cleaned_data:
            if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match. Please try again!")
        return self.cleaned_data

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm,self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
#The save(commit=False) tells Django to save the new record, but dont commit it to the database yet

class AuthenticationForm(forms.Form): #forms.Form Not forms.ModelForm

    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=
    {'class': 'form-control','type':'text','name': 'email','placeholder':'Email'}), label="Email")

    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=
    {'class':'form-control','type':'password', 'name': 'password','placeholder':'Password'}),label="Password")

    class Meta:
        fields = ['email', 'password']
```

views.py :

```
# encoding=utf8
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, redirect, render, HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.contrib.auth import login as django_login, logout as django_logout, authenticate as django_authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import AuthenticationForm, RegistrationForm


def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data = request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = request.POST['email']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = django_authenticate(email=email, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    django_login(request,user)
                    return redirect('/dashboard')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()

    return render_to_response('own/index.html',{'form':form,}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(data = request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            # messages.success(request, "Thank you for signing up")
            return redirect('/dashboard')

    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()

    return render_to_response('own/signup.html',{'form':form,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def logout(request):
    django_logout(request)
    return redirect('/')

@login_required(login_url ="/")
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'own/dashboard.html',{})
```

admin.py :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from ca.models import CampusAmbassador
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

class CampusAmbassadorAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    list_display = ('email','name','college','is_staff')
    list_filter = ('is_staff',)
    fieldsets = (
    (None,{'fields':('email','password')}),
    ('Personal info',{'fields':('name','college')}),
    ('Permissions',{'fields':('is_staff',)}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'name','college', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )
    search_fields =('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()

admin.site.register(CampusAmbassador, CampusAmbassadorAdmin)
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

ERROR :

[image: error]

Note: when I fill the 'Name' as a email id, it works but not otherwise, as you can see it in college field.

Please help.

Comment: In your `RegistrationForm` you have defined all of `name`, `college` and `email` as `EmailField`s... so Django is checking to see whether they are valid email addresses. You probably don't want `name` and `college` to be `CharField`s.

Comment: @solarissmoke Silly mistake that was!!, thank you for your kind efforts.